# Delphi with indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy10

I just started using indy10 (today) in Delphi 2010, after reading everywere i managed to make it work, i can send emails using gmail, it works fine on my computer, but when i install the application on my laptop (for tests), it doesnt send the email and my app stops working, do i have to install something else on my laptop or how can i make it to work on every computer i install my program, so far i have to install it on 6 different computers, some use windows XP and some Windows 7, i hope there is a way to make it multiplatform or something.

This is my code:

```
procedure SendIndyMail;
begin

    Form_final.IdSMTP1 .IOHandler := Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Host:= 'smtp.gmail.com';
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Password:= 'xxxxxx';
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Port := 587;
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Username := 'xxxxxx';

    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Destination := 'smtp.gmail.com:587';
    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Port := 587;
    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    Form_final.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    Form_final.IdMessage1.Subject:=conect.Q_selec_info_generalDescripcion.Text+' '+DateToStr(Date);
    Form_final.IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses:=conect.Q_config_seleccorreo.Text;
    TIdAttachmentFile.Create(Form_final.IdMessage1.MessageParts, conect.Q_config_selecfolder.Text+'\reporte_'+FormatDateTime('dddd d of mmmm yyyy', Date)+' Inventario '+Form_inventario.Edit_id_inventario.Text+'.pdf');

    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Connect;
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Send(Form_final.IdMessage1);
    Form_final.IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```

I ran the proyect on my laptop and it says:

Could not load SSL Library, now, i did many things to make it work, downloaded many things and tried many other, now i dont know where those libraries are and how to retrieve them, and i would like to know of a way to load them with the installation so my installer goes with everything needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EDN article outlining which dlls to deploy: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31279

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the OpenSSL DLLs on your target machines, preferrably in your app's installation folder.  If you still get the error, Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit can tell you why it could not load the OpenSSL DLLs.  As for the DLLs themselves, you can download Indy-compatible copies from Indy's [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

On a side note, you do not need to set the IOHandler's `Destination`, `Host`, or `Port` properties.  The `Connect()` method will handle that internally for you.

Comment: thanks, took me some time to install the correct OpenSSL on my lap but i managed to do it